# how to use "leaflet-buffer" in react-leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.draw, react-leaflet-draw

I want to buffer the shapes
I drew on the react-leaflet.
But I can't find any npm library to react like "leaflet-buffer".
Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a way of doing it using turf buffer package. Check this sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/hue8o?file=/src/index.js

But I need to try it for myself and try this result here